# Trouble with capturing a group of users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get a subset of users. I want to capture a list of groups members but only those who have a canonical name that starts with "contoso.com" Here is the code snippet hopefully someone can help me.

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName | where{$_.ObjectClass -eq "User"} | Get-ADUser -Properties CanonicalName | Select CanonicalName | where{$_.CanonicalName -Like "contonso.com"}
```

Comment: What is the actual question? What is the "trouble" you're having?

Comment: It will not return any results even if the User Account Canonical Name does contain contonso.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a wildcard so that the remaining characters in the CanonicalName will match something in the `-like` criteria:

```
...where{$_.CanonicalName -Like "contonso.com*"}
#                        add a wildcard here ^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | where{$_.ObjectClass -eq "User"} | Get-ADUser -Properties CanonicalName | where{$_.CanonicalName -match "contoso.com"} | select Canonicalname,name
```

Comment: `where{$_.CanonicalName -like "contoso.com*"} | select Canonicalname,name` both works